Flutter Android namespace issue after updating gradle plugin
After doing some updates to fix the declarative block gradle warning , I've had an issue with compiling my app for production. I get warnings for unexpected kotlin version (expected 1.7.0, actual 1.9), and when I launch the apk, I get an instant fatal error:
[frame_perf] perfboost open tb_ctl file failed, isApp[1], errno=No such file or directory
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: com.my.app.stg, PID: 18292
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app.stg/com.biosphere.terrai.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~4WIGO53JC8kZEYhSkFIcLA==/com.my.app.stg-MBmo_L3L_l4N55Phv57l2A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~4WIGO53JC8kZEYhSkFIcLA==/com.my.app.stg-MBmo_L3L_l4N55Phv57l2A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~4WIGO53JC8kZEYhSkFIcLA==/com.my.app.stg-MBmo_L3L_l4N55Phv57l2A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]                                                                                                    

So after getting that error, I decided to upgrade Gradle version to latest and update everything so that 1.9 would become the expected Kotlin version and all would be good. So I started the AGP upgrade assistant and upgraded to gradle 8.7.
Now I can't build the app at all and I'm getting a new error relative to the Android namespace
* What went wrong:
Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.
> Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@be57342 of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':appcenter_sdk_flutter'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
         > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file

Which is weird because I already did that in android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterDefaults = [
        versionCode: '1',
        versionName: '1.0',
        minSdkVersion: '24'
]

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode', flutterDefaults.versionCode).toInteger()
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName', flutterDefaults.versionName)
def flutterMinSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion', flutterDefaults.minSdkVersion).toInteger()

android {
    namespace "com.my.app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion flutterMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "env"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "[DEV] myApp"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "env"
            applicationIdSuffix ".stg"
            versionNameSuffix "-stg"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "[STG] myApp"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "env"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "myApp"
        }
    }

    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        if (!project.hasProperty('android.injected.build.model')
                && taskGraph.allTasks.any { it.name.toLowerCase().equals("assembledebug") || it.name.toLowerCase().equals("assemblerelease") }) {
            throw new Exception("Please specify a flavor with --flavor <dev/staging/prod>")
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}


The official documentation says the namespace should be define in android/build.gradle, but when I do I get an error that the method android() doesn't exist on root project 'android'.
I've read that a workaround involving an afterEvaluate method could work, so I did this in the android/build.gradle:
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Which causes an error:  Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.
I've also read about adding this to fix the issue:
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

But then I get an error that the plugin for onesignal is missing, and adding it feels like a headache on its own.
Any idea how to solve this issue and finally build my app ?
Thanks !

Try with Flutter pub cache clean , Flutter pub cache repair , Flutter pub get .

@RahulKushwaha problem persists, either project already evaluated or onesignal gradle plugin not found if I add the last 2 lines I mentionned in the post
